# put string into a map using operator [ ]

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, operators, addition

I have a `map<int,string>` to add `name` for each `id`.
I have a method to do this.

```
void User::add(int id, string name) {
    map<int, string>::iterator it = map.find(id);
    if (it == map.end()) {
        map.insert(pair<int, string>(id, name));
    } else {
        it->second = name;
    }
}
```

it worked perfectly fine. But I want to learn how to use the operator [] to add string into a map. Below is my code :

```
void user::add(int id, string name) {
    &auto findUser = map[id];//check if an user exists
    findUser.push_back(string()); // add a new string object
    findUser.push_back(name); // put string into the map
}
```

When I run this code, it gave me an error : no viable conversion from 'string'

Comment: Recommend not having a map named map for readability's sake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    &auto findUser = map[id];//check if an user exists
```

First, I assume the leading `&` is a typo because it makes no sense on that side of the declaration.

`map[id]` is going to find the string mapped to id. If there is no such string [*the map will invent one*, stuff it into the map, and return a reference to the brand new string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at). You will always get a string reference back.

Because you will be returned a string reference, `auto findUser` will be a string reference. The rest of the code is trying to push strings into strings and you've seen the results of that. This is one of the dangers of `auto`. As much as I love it, it hid the actual data type from OP and made the error messages that much more arcane.

You cannot use `[]` as a check for presence in a map effectively. Sure, you can test for empty string, but now you have an empty string cluttering up your map. Soon you have many empty strings in the map. Not a good solution.

map.find is about as good as it gets to test for presence. The next best is probably [map.at(id)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) because it will throw an exception if the id is not found.

On the upside, because `[]` returns a reference to a the mapped type it can be used exactly as you would an array.

```
name = map[id];
map[id] = name;
```

are both valid. You could also take a pointer, but this carries risk. If the map is changed your pointer will likely be invalid.

Answer (score 2):

This is very simple:

```
void user::add(int id, string name) 
{
    map[id] = name;
}
```

Comment: Do note, however, that this one is blind. It will replace the name at id, something OP has gone to lengths to avoid in the initial cut.

Comment: Well. He is replacing name for the existing `id` in the original code. If he is wanting to avoid that, there would be `return` instead of `it->second = name;`

Comment: No. In the original code OP tests for the presence of `id` and only adds the string if it does not exist. This is something maps `operator[]` cannot do.